# How to sort an array of objects with respect to a particular field in controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects in a scope variable and now I want to sort this array with respect to a particular object ( a date field)   and display. I have mentioned the logic below

```
<ion-option-button role="button"  data-ng-click="save(data)"></ion-option-button>
```

Controller:

```js
$scope.save = function(data) {
   var action='save';
   //service call happens and response is returned

   if (response.isSuccessful === true && response.responseCode == "1") {

      vm.data = moveElementInArray(vm.data, data, 0);
      //perform sorting with respect to a date field after moving to index 0 , vm.data contains the array objects
   }
};
```

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try using $filter

```
arr = $filter('orderBy')(arr, 'Date', true);
```

see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)